# Add new lighting before previous lighting doesn't work

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

This is my current switch, light and power source and it works fine

[image]

(Red circle is wire nut for better visualization to the real scene)

I tried to add a new light BEFORE the power source but it doesn't work. In fact, there is no power at all

[image]

But if I "jump" from the Light 1 to Light 3, it works

[image]

This last scenario is not idea as I have to drill holes through joists.

What I tried to understand is why Light 2 does not work above?

Comment: So, in diagram 1, it looks like you have two boxes and the neutral is in a different box than the hot? It also looks like the switch is controlling the flow back to the neutral (which isn't good). Can you clarify?

Comment: The power source is not a box. It's just 2 black/white wires running from another wall. I am not sure if I understand "neutral is in a different box than the hot". I think you are right that "switch is controlling the flow back to the neutral" as the switch is to connect or disconnect the black wire (hot). But what's wrong with that? I found out this house has this wiring all over the places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your figure 2, when the switch is closed (i.e. turned on), both wires of light2 are connected to hot (but one before switch, one after switch), therefore light2 gets not power.

Suppose you want to use the switch to control both lights, the correct wiring should be the same as light1: one wire to hot after switch, the other wire to neutral. That's your figure 3.

Comment: So maybe I understood something fundamental. I thought when the switch is closed, Light 1 gets power and therefore the black wire is hot, which is also the same black wire as Light 2. Isn't that NOT the case?

Comment: A light gets power when one wire is connected to hot and the other connected to neutral. In your figure 2, the "same black wire as Light 2" is indeed hot, but the other wire of Light 2 is also connected to hot, so Light 2 gets no power. If both wires of a light are connected to the same line, whether that line is hot or neutral, the light gets no power.

Comment: There is also a confusion regarding which is "hot". My assumption is that your switch is correctly controlling hot (instead of neutral), i.e. the white line in your diagram  connecting "switch" and "power source" is hot. If not the case (i.e. your switch is controlling the neutral, it is dangerous and must be corrected), then Light 2 gets not power because both wires are connected to neutral.

Comment: The color is exactly depicted reality of the wiring. Thanks for clearing this out.

Comment: Then your original wiring, as shown in Figure 1, is already wrong. There are two possibilities: either the two wires from the power source are using the wrong colors (i.e. white is hot and black is neutral), or your switch is controlling the neutral wire (which is *dangerous* and must be corrected).

Comment: Wrong wiring is possible. It's the old house. What is your suggestion to change switch to control hot wire instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82701/discussion-between-user12075-and-hp).

Answer (score 2):

"It works" is not a measure of quality.  The first problem I see is that someone has confused black and white coming from the power source and they go the opposite places from where they should!  Exchange them.

- Power supplies deliver **Always-Hot** and **Neutral**.
- Switches require **Always-Hot** and deliver **Switched-Hot**.
- Lamps require **Switched-Hot** and **Neutral**.

If you are wondering "What is the difference between hot and neutral? This is **AC Power**" that's beyond the scope of this answer, but it has a real answer.

Now you notice all cables come in black, white and safety ground. Yet we already have named 3 wire *functions* - how do we get 3 wire functions on 2 colors of wire?  If any random wire can have any random function, this rapidly becomes **exactly the dizzying nightmare you are dealing with**. Anyone would lose their mind!  The way to regain it is something not required by Code (much):

[image]

*Now* let's see what our wiring looks like.   Now, white = Neutral, black = Always-Hot, red = Switched-Hot.  We will tape wires as-needed.  Wires marked with tape are now that color.

[image]

This is legal/correct.  I fixed the crisscrossed supply wires.   Note how white is remarked black when there's already a black there, that satisfies two Code requirements.  (Actually, since 2008, Code requires *real* neutral *also* be supplied in switch loops.)

Marking the Switched-Hot wires red is not Code mandatory, *but boy, does it make this diagram clearer!*

Now let's do that to your second diagram and see if it gives us any clues.

[image]

*Well there's your trouble!*  Lamps don't take **Hot** and **Switched-Hot**!  This can't work. Lamp needs neutral, and it has to go get it from somewhere.

Perhaps it's time to modernize the switch-loop wiring to the /3 cable which provides real neutral also. E.G.

[image]

Comment: This is an awesome response. However, due to ceiling and wall, it's hard for me to run another cable from the switch.